# Python: How can I find the differences between two lists of strings?

Tags: python, string, list

I'm using Python 3. I have two lists of strings and I'm looking for mismatches between the two. The code I have works for smaller lists but not the larger lists I'm writing it for.

Input from the non-working lists is in the following format:

```
mmec11.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec13.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec12.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec14.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
```

My function to compare two lists of data in the above format is:

```
result = []
for x in mmeList1:
    if x not in mmeList2:
        result.append(x)
return result
```

The problem is it's not working. I get an output file of both lists combined into one long list. When I put a test is to say "Hi" every time a match was made, nothing happened. Does anyone have any ideas where I'm going wrong. I work for a telecommunications company and we're trying to go through large database dumps to find missing MMEs.

I'm wondering if maybe my input function is broken? The function is:

```
for line in input:
        field = line.split()
        tempMME = field[0]
        result.append(tempMME)
```

I'm not very experienced with this stuff and I'm wondering if the line.split() function is messing up due to the periods in the MME names?

Thank you for any and all help!

Comment: Please post a sample input and expected output

Comment: You should also add the items from list 2 that are missing in list 1, but your code seems ok

Comment: Do you want to check for items that exist in either but not both lists, or do you want to compare items at corresponding indices?

Comment: I want to check for items that exist in either but not both lists. Order doesn't matter because the goal is to remove typos from our databases without having to go through hundreds of spreadsheets. The sample input is just like the four lines posted above, only each file has around 150 entries. I copied the four lines above from one of the files I'm working with. I dunno...

Answer (score 11):

If you don't need to preserve ordering, the following will result in all mmes that exist in list2 but not list1.

```
result = list(set(mmeList2) - set(mmeList1))
```

Comment: I appreciate the help. I copied and pasted this code into my program and commented out my code. It gave me the same result I've been getting. When I try my program with different lists of Wu-Tang affiliated rappers, it works fine. But thank you!

Comment: I have some egg on my face. If I use two text files, your solution works well. I'm comparing input from a .csv and a .txt, so it looks like I know where the break is. :)

Answer (score 3):

I tested your compare function and it's working fine, assuming that the data in mmeList1 and mmeList2 is correct.

For example, I ran a test of your compare function using the following data.

mmeList1:

```
mmec11.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec13.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec12.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec14.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
```

mmeList2:

```
mmec11.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec13.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec12.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
mmec15.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
```

Result contained:

```
mmec14.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org
```

I suspect the problem is that mmeList1 and mmeList2 don't contain what you think they contain. Unfortunately, we can't help you more without seeing how mmeList1 and mmeList2 are populated.

If you want to see the differences in both, (i.e. Result should contain mmec14 AND mmec15), then what you want to use is Sets.

For example:

```
mmeSet1 = set(mmecList1)
mmeSet2 = set(mmecList2)

print mmeSet1.symmetric_difference(mmeSet2)
```

will result in:

```
['mmec14.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org', 'mmec15.mmegifffa.mme.epc.mnc980.mcc310.3gppnetwork.org']
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think your suspicion is a bad one, but sadly I know exactly what the files contain. Each is about 150 lines of the above. The problem we have is the technicians sometimes make typos which then go on to populate many databases. We're trying to find a way to quickly sort out those typos without going through each file on our own. I gave your solution a try and I'm getting the same results of a list with every mme name.

Comment: I owe you a HUGE apology. It turns out the problem was very close to your suspicion. The files I'm working with are .csv and .txt files. I would have never though to test that being the break if not for your insightful comment. Thank you!!

Comment: No worries, bud. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

At first, using set() on list is best way for decreasing iteration.Try this one

```
result = []
a=list(set(mmeList1))
b=list(set(mmeList2))
for x in a:
    if x not in b:
        result.append(x)
return result
```

Comment: I'm not following. You're converting a list to a set back to a list. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Unfortunately, this example (like the original) runs in exponential time.

Comment: @NathanielMallet, it is for decreasing quantity of iteration. There's difference.

Comment: @JamesEmerton's way is very simple, optimal and true, it's also based on set()

Comment: @SanjarStone, you are using sets in the most illogical and inefficient way

Comment: @SanjarStone - How is it "Decreasing quantity of iterations?" The result is a list with the same number of elements as your staring point.

Comment: @NathanielMallet, it is said that there's large dumps database. Reading dumps line by line and copying to list requires much time. And why again must be used list on iteration? Using set instead of list best way in this problem.